# Entity Framework Core - Finding data in another table using a lambda function

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables. `Account` and `Tenant`. There are many accounts to a tenant and this has been configured in the DbContext as follows.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Tenant)
            .WithMany(a => a.Accounts)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The Account POCO class is as follows.

```
public class Account : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string? AccountName { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? AccountFirstName { get; set; }
        public string? AccountLastName { get; set; }
        public string? MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? Address1 { get; set; }
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }


        public string? PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public string? VerificationToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Verified { get; set; }
        public bool IsVerified => Verified.HasValue || PasswordReset.HasValue;
        public string? ResetToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ResetTokenExpires { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PasswordReset { get; set; }
        
        public List<RefreshToken>? RefreshTokens { get; set; }

        public bool OwnsToken(string token)
        {
            return this.RefreshTokens?.Find(x => x.Token == token) != null;
        }

        // One tenant to many user accounts
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tenant? Tenant { get; set; }

        // One suburb to many User accounts
        public int SuburbId { get; set; }
        public virtual Suburb? Suburb { get; set; }
    }
```

The Tenant POCO class is as follows:

```
public class Tenant : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
    {
        public Tenant()
        {
            Accounts = new List<Account>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TenantNo { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ABN { get; set; }
        public string CompanyAccountEmail { get; set; }
        public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ContactLastName { get; set; }
        public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string BankBSB { get; set; }
        public string BankAccount { get; set; }

        public int SuburbId { get; set; }
        public virtual Suburb Suburb { get; set; }

        // Many users to one tenant
        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; }
    }
```

N ogiven there are multiple accounts to a tenant or "many accounts to one tenant" how,
if I have the account ID, obtain the tenantId using a lambda function.

I tried to use the following but got lost.

```
await tenantsContext.Accounts.Include(x => x.Tenant).Where(x => x.Id == accountId).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => new Tenant.. and lost it here..
```

Can someone show me and others how you would, given an accountId (which equates to the Id of the account table) and get the TenantId for that account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get TenantId for account with given accountId using this:

```
await tenantsContext.Accounts
    .Where(x => x.Id == accountId)
    .Select(x => x.TenantId)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```